# Inequality $\sum^{k}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=k}{{1}\over{j - i + 1}} \le n$

Tags: inequality, summation

I was proving a statement and have finished all the other part, the remaining boiling down to proving the inequality below (if I proved the other part correctly):

$$\sum^{k}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=k}{{1}\over{j - i + 1}} \le n$$

where $1 \le i \le k \le j \le n$.

I wrote a simple function taking $k$ and $n$ as parameters to compute the left side and the result never exceeds $n$. Also it seems that the maximum is reached when $k = n / 2$. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks...

Comment: Do you mean to say that the maximum, instead of minimum, is reached at $k=\frac{n}{2}$? Bounding the summation with integral which is a sum of $x\ln(x)$ may work. There are a few small correction terms need to be taken care of...

Comment: @Hans Thanks for pointing that out, Hans! Sorry for the typo... Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof: Define $s=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=k}{{1}\over{j - i + 1}}$. We prove the required inequality by factoring out common and distinct summand $\frac{1}{d+1}$, where $d=j-i$. The region of summation $\{1,2,...,k\}\times\{k,k+1,...,n\}$ is partitioned into 3 parts, with 2 isosceles right triangles sandwiching 1 parallelogram with two 45 degree angles. We distinguish 2 cases:

1) $n\le 2k-1$

The summation over the 3 partitions are:
$$\begin{align}
s_1 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{d+1}{d+1}, \\
s_2 &= \sum_{d=1}^{2k-n-1} \frac{n-k+1}{n-k+1+d}, \\
s_3 &= \sum_{d=1}^{n-k} \frac{n-k+1-d}{k+d} = (n+1)\sum_{d=1}^{n-k}\frac{1}{k+d} - (n-k).
\end{align}$$
Since the summands are decreasing function of d, we bound the summations by the integration of the summands.

$$s_2 < (n-k+1)\int_0^{2k-n-1}\frac{1}{n-k+1+x}=(n-k+1)\ln\frac{k}{n-k+1},$$
and
$$s_3+n-k < (n+1)\int_0^{n-k}\frac{1}{k+x}dx=(n+1)\ln\frac{n}{k}.$$

2) $n\ge 2k-1$

$$\begin{align}
s_1 &= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{d+1}{d+1} = k, \\
s_2 &= k\sum_{d=1}^{n-2k+1} \frac{1}{k+d} <k\int_0^{n-2k+1}\frac{1}{k+x}dx = k\ln\frac{n+1-k}{k}, \\
s_3 &= \sum_{d=1}^{k-1} \frac{d}{n-d+1} = (n+1)\sum_{d=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n+1-i}-(k-1) \\
&<(n+1)\int_1^k \frac{1}{n+1-x}dx = (n+1)\ln\frac{n}{n+1-k}-(k-1).
\end{align}$$

---

For both cases, put the parts $s_1, s_2, s_3$ together, we get the same expression
$$\begin{align}s &=s_1+s_2+s_3 \\
&= (n+1)\ln n - \big(k\ln k + (n+1-k)\ln(n+1-k)\big)+1 \\
&< (n+1)\ln n - (n+1)\ln\frac{n+1}{2} +1 \\
&\text{by the convexity of the function } x\ln x \\
&< (n+1)\Big(\ln 2-\frac{1}{n+1} \Big)+1 \\
& = (n+1)\ln 2 \\
&< 0.7(n+1).
\end{align}$$

This actually gives a slightly tighter bound for $s$. We only need to check the inequality for $n\in\{1,2\}$ to complete the proof.

Also, this proof points the way to showing $s$ achieves maximum at $k \cong \frac{n+1}{2}$ for fixed $n$.

QED

Comment: Thank you so much, Hans! Like in your solution, bounding with $xln x$ at the right time is important. One of my previous trials involves replacing each item with the maximum one and then apply the logarithm bounding, which exceeds the RHS of the inequality. Yes, as you have pointed out, maximum is reached when $k$ is in the middle - sorry for the typo. All in all, a brilliant and meticulous solution!

Answer (score 1):

Denote your sum by $s$. After some rewriting of summation variables one has
$$s=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{1\over i+j+1}\ .$$
Now the function
$$(x,y)\mapsto{1\over x+y+1}\qquad(x+y>-1)$$
is convex. It follows that
$${1\over i+j+1}\leq\int_{i-1/2}^{i+1/2}\int_{j-1/2}^{j+1/2}{dx\>dy\over 1+x+y}\ .$$
Summing all these integrals up one obtains
$$s\leq \int_{-1/2}^{k-1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{n-k+1/2}{dx\>dy\over 1+x+y}=:J\ .$$
Mathematica  computes the last integral to
$$J=(n+1)\log(n+1)-k\log k-(n+1-k)\log(n+1-k)\ .$$
I leave it to you to analyze this expression. The case $n=50$ and $1\leq k\leq n$ is shown in the following figure. It corroborates the findings of @Hans.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this alternative and more general approach, @Christian! Both of you made use of logarithm functions' convexity, which turns out to be crucial to the proof. $J'|_k = 0$ when $k = {n + 1 \over 2}$, where the maximum is reached. Substituting $k = {n + 1 \over 2}$ back yields $J = (n + 1) \ln {(n + 1)}$, same as @Hans's result. Thanks again for taking your time looking at this problem!

Comment: (By the way, I will vote up this answer after I am eligible to do so, which requires 15 reputation points... Sorry about that...)